# Add and read data in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have set of data in Excel sheet. I want to create a android app to read these details. It is like a result sheet. When the user enters the index number the app will show the results.

What is the best way to do this? I know it is hard to use Excel with this. Can I use a text file and get the details from it? Or do I need to create a SQLite database and enter the all details via the source code.

Comment: Will this Excel document be updated often? Daily, quarterly, or never? Depending on the answer to that, the best way may be different.

Comment: No It does not updated often. May be yearly or never.

Comment: So you could manually convert to SQL, or use a build-time script to do it for you. SQLite would definitely be faster than using an XLS parsing library. Is the spreadsheet file large? Does the app need to perform quickly? If either of the above is true, I would use SQLite as Moje suggests.

Comment: Can you explain how to convert manually to SQLite? The file is not a large file.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db for the Android documentation on SQLite usage in Android. Explaining how to write SQL commands is outside the scope of the Question, and not what StackOverflow is best used for. It's easy to search for "how to write SQL" and find lots of good guides and tutorials.

Comment: No I do not need the SQL statements. You are telling that it is better to create SQLite database for this?

Comment: Yes. And to do that, you have to create SQL INSERT statements. Or I guess you could use a tool like SQLite Database Browser and create the database via a GUI. But you'll still have to use SQL SELECT commands to pull it out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will be querying your data often.
You will definitely be better off with SQLite.

Comment: No It does not updated often. May be yearly or never. They does not change.